# Error cloning Conda env arcgispro-py3 on an ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, anaconda

Whenever I try to clone the base package that comes with ArcGIS Server I get an error saying:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::notebook-5.7.8-py36_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. <USER>\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\pkgs\notebook-5.7.8-py36_0\Lib\site-packages\notebook\i18n\zh_CN\LC_MESSAGES\nbjs.json
```

Can I install Anaconda onto the server and will this help fix the problem?